# React-native: how to remove list lines?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-listview

I'm using `React Native`, I want to remove lines from list but i can't,I set borderBottomWidth to 0 but it didn't work, this is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppRegistry, Image, ImageBackground, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, 
FlatList } from "react-native";
import { Container, Content, Text, List, ListItem, Icon, Left, Body, Right, 
 } from "native-base";
const routes = [{"title":"Specials","icon":"menu"}, {"title": 
"Home","icon":"home"}, {"title":"Shopping Cart","icon":"cart"},
            {"title":"Wishlist","icon":"heart"},{"title":"My 
    Orders","icon":"menu"},{"title":"Categories","icon":"list"},
            {"title":"Gift Vouchers","icon":"menu"}, 
   {"title":"Affiliates","icon":"menu"},{"title":"Returns","icon":"menu"},
            {"title":"My Account","icon":"menu"},
    {"title":"Settings","icon":"menu"}, {"title":"Contact 
    Us","icon":"menu"},
            {"title":"About","icon":"menu"},{"title":"Service 
         Center","icon":"menu"},
            {"title":"Rate Us On Google Play","icon":"menu"},
       {"title":"Logout","icon":"menu"}];

export default class SideBar extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <Container>
     <Content>
      <ImageBackground  source={require('../../assets/nav.png')} style={{
          height: 150,
          alignSelf: "stretch",
          alignItems: "center",
          flexDirection:'row'
        }}>
        <Image
          style={{ height: 80, width: 80, borderRadius: 64, marginLeft: 25}}
          source={{
            uri: "http://safe-
               pay.co/safepay/public/uploadedimg/user/avatar.png"
           }}
           />
           <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 25}}>
            <Text style= {{color: 'white'}}>Nima</Text>
            <Text style={styles.emailText}>Nima33@gmail.com</Text>
         </View>
       </ImageBackground>
       <List
        dataArray={routes}
        renderRow={data => {
          return (
            <ListItem
              style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}
              button
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.title)}
              icon>
              <Left>
                <Icon name={data.icon} style={{color:'gray'}}/>
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Text>{data.title}</Text>
              </Body>
            </ListItem>
          );
        }}
      />
    </Content>
  </Container>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 emailText: {
  fontSize: 12,
  color: 'white'
 }
})
```

This is the output:
[image: This is the output Image]

I set `noLines` and `noBottomBorder` as prop but they didn't work,If i set `ottomBorderWidth:2` the bottom line size increase in width and height, Is these lines must be in list or there is any eay to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

You should set **noBorder** as prop: `<ListItem noBorder>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply `borderBottomWidth:0` in `<List>` instead of `<ListItem>` like below.

```
<List
    dataArray={routes}
    containerStyle={borderBottomWidth: 0}
    renderRow={data => {
      return (
        <ListItem
          style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}}
          button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.title)}
          icon>
          <Left>
            <Icon name={data.icon} style={{color:'gray'}}/>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Text>{data.title}</Text>
          </Body>
        </ListItem>
      );
    }}
  />
```

Comment: I apply it in list but the I got the same output

Answer (score 0):

Apply `borderBottomWidth:0` to `ListItem` and `Body`. If there is no `Body` then `ListItem` should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, just set the `borderColor:white`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property property `bottomDivider` as `false` at the `ListItem` component.